# Python Import Conventions: explicit bin/lib imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, python-import, python-unittest

**ADVICE REQUEST:  Best Practices for Python Imports**

I need advice re: how major projects do Python imports and the standard / Pythonic way to set this up.

I have a project **Foobar** that's a subproject of another, much larger and well-used project **Dammit**.  My project directory looks like this:

```
/opt/foobar
/opt/foobar/bin/startFile.py
/opt/foobar/bin/tests/test_startFile.py
/opt/foobar/foobarLib/someModule.py
/opt/foobar/foobarLib/tests/test_someModule.py
```

So, for the Dammit project, I add to PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/foobar
```

This lets me add a very clear, easy-to-track-down import of:

```
from foobarLib.someModule import SomeClass
```

to all 3 of: 
* Dammit - using foobarLib in the import makes everyone know it's not in Dammit project, it's in Foobar.
* My startFile.py is an adjunct process that has the same pythonpath import.
* test_someModule.py has an explicit import, too.

PROBLEM:  This only works for foobarLib, not bin.

I have tests I want to run on in /opt/foobar/bin/tests/test_startFile.py.  But, how to set up the path and do the import?  Should I do a relative import like this:

```
PROJ_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJ_ROOT)
```

Or, should I rename the bin dir to be foobarBin so I do the import as:

```
from foobarBin.startFile import StartFile
```

I'm tempted to do the following:

```
/opt/foobarProject/foobar
/opt/foobarProject/foobar/bin/startFile.py
/opt/foobarProject/foobar/bin/tests/test_startFile.py
/opt/foobarProject/foobar/foobarLib/someModule.py
/opt/foobarProject/foobar/foobarLib/tests/test_someModule.py
```

then, I can do all my imports with:

```
import foobar.bin.startFile
import foobar.lib.someModule
```

Basically, for large Python projects (AND THEIR ADJUNCTS), it seems to me we have goals of:

- minimize number of dirs added to pythonpath;
- make it obvious where imports are coming from.  That is, people use 'import lib.thing' a lot, and if there's more than one directory in the pythonpath named 'lib', 
  it's troublesome / non-obvious where that is, short of invoking 
  python and searching sys.modules, etc.
- minimize number of times we add paths to sys.path since that's runtime and somewhat non-obvious.

I've used Python a long time, and been part of projects that do it various ways, some of them more stupid and some less so.  I guess I'm wondering if there is a best-practices here, and the reason for it?  Is my convention of adding foobarProject layer okay, good, bad, or just one more way among many?

Comment: Are `bin` and `tests` packages (that is, do they have `__init__.py`)?

Comment: Yes, I've switched to using the thing I was 'tempted' to do, above, and have added *__init__.py* files to support that.  I still want to hear opinions.